# Slowly decrement variable with timer?

Tags: python, pygame

I've got a variable that increases when the user presses a button.
When the user presses another button, I'd like to set that variable to 0,
but not instantly-- I'd like it to tick down over the course of a few seconds.
During this time I'd like the user to be able to perform other actions-- hence why I'm not using sleep.

I've looked at using pygame's events, time.clock, etc., but I can't seem to get this to work. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
import pygame, sys, math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
scrw = 640
scrh = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((scrw, scrh))

ttwist = 0
recentering = False
fps = 15

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 12)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if not recentering:
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            ttwist +=1
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            ttwist -=1   

    RECENTERTORSOEVENT = USEREVENT
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN  and event.key == pygame.K_BACKSLASH:
        recentering = True
        pygame.time.set_timer(RECENTERTORSOEVENT, 1000*abs(ttwist))
        if ttwist == 0:
            recentering = False

    if event.type == USEREVENT:
       if ttwist < 0:
        ttwist += 1
       elif ttwist > 0:
        ttwist -= 1

    drawtext = my_font.render("TTWIST:"+str(ttwist), True, (255,255,255),(0,0,0))
    screen.blit(drawtext,(10,130))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you create an [mcve] please?

Comment: I have added all the relevant code-- thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but some parts of the code need to be changed:

- All the `if event.type == ...` blocks should be inside of the event loop.
- `RECENTERTORSOEVENT = USEREVENT` should be defined above the while loop (but that doesn't cause problems).
- You're setting the time interval for the `RECENTERTORSOEVENT` way too high: `1000*abs(ttwist)`. That means, if the `ttwist` is 10, you're setting it to 10.000 ms (10 seconds). Just set it to a constant value like 100 ms.
- When the `ttwist` is recentered, call `pygame.time.set_timer(RECENTERTORSOEVENT, 0)` to stop the timer.
- Fill the screen each frame `screen.fill((30, 30, 30))`, otherwise you see artifacts because the font surface keeps changing its size.

---

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 22)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

ttwist = 0
RECENTERTORSOEVENT = pygame.USEREVENT

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                print('recentering')
                # Start to add the USEREVENT every 100 ms.
                pygame.time.set_timer(RECENTERTORSOEVENT, 100)
        elif event.type == RECENTERTORSOEVENT:
            ttwist += 1 if ttwist < 0 else -1
            if ttwist == 0:
                print('done')
                # Stop to add the USEREVENT to the queue.
                pygame.time.set_timer(RECENTERTORSOEVENT, 0)

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_d]:
        ttwist += 1
    if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
        ttwist -= 1

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    drawtext = my_font.render(
        'TTWIST: {}'.format(ttwist), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(drawtext, (10, 130))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

---

`ttwist += 1 if ttwist < 0 else -1` is a conditional expression and does basically the same as:

```
if ttwist < 0:
    ttwist += 1
elif ttwist > 0:
    ttwist -= 1
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you for your help; I've got a better grasp on how things work now!